# Why is the Cartesian product $X\times X$ an ordering of $X$?

Tags: order-theory

> It should be remarked that the definition of ordering is not very restrictive. For example, **$X\times X$ is an ordering of $X,$ but a rather *uninteresting* one**. Relative to this ordering, each member of $X$ is an upper bound, and in fact a supremum, of every subset. The more interesting  satisfy the further conditions: if $x$ is less than or equal to $y$ and $y$ is less than or equal to $x,$ than $y=x\,.$ In this case there is at most one supremum for a set, and at most infimum.

This is excerpted from *Orderings* from *John Kelley*'s *General Topology*.

Hmm; I stumbled upon the very first part of the excerpt:

What did Kelley mean by that *the definition of ordering is not very restrictive*?

How is the Cartesian Product $X\times X$ an *ordering* of $X\,?$

Comment: What is the definition of an ordering on $X$?

Comment: @Christoph, I must say I'm not sure whether Kelley uses $X$ from his discussion above where he takes $X$ to be _order-complete_. And by _ordering_ generally, he means _partial ordering_.

Comment: The usual definition of a partial order includes antisymmetry, which is in general not satisfied by $X\times X$. That's why I'm asking for the definition of *ordering* in your context.

Comment: As I said, @Christoph, Kelley meant partial ordering by _ordering_.

Comment: Then what is the definition of "partial ordering"?

Comment: @Christoph, He didn't define anything; he just wrote "_[...] Ordering(partial ordering)..._" assuming that the readers are aware of the definition. As that of the definition, the relation must be reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric.

Comment: He gives a definition in the first sentence of the section. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From page 13 of the book:

> An ordering **(partial ordering, quasi-ordering)** is a transitive
>   relation. A relation $<$ orders **(partially orders)** a set $X$ iff it is
>   transitive on $X$.

Thus, a subset $R$ of $X\times X$ is an ordering of $X$ if and only if for $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ we always have $(x,z)\in R$. This is obviously satisfied by $R=X\times X$ and hence $X\times X$ is an ordering of $X$.

Comment: Okay, so Kelley defines partial ordering as ordering which is transitive; why did he not take the _reflexive, antisymmetric_ criteria? But this has provided an insight; thanks, +1.

Comment: Could you tell @Christoph; what did Kelley mean when he wrote the definition of ordering is not _very restrictive_?

Comment: It means, that it allows for relations to be called "ordering" which don't seem to *order* anything, in the intuitive interpretation of the word. Hence the example of an ordering such that we can have $x<y$ and $y<x$ for distinct $x$ and $y$. I dislike this definition, and haven't seen it used anywhere else. But in the context of the book, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> What did Kelley mean by that *the definition of ordering is not very restrictive*?

It means that even things that don't look very much like orderings at all are counted as "orderings". One example is given: $X \times X$.

An ordering is a relation on $X$ -- that is, a subset $R \subseteq X \times X$ -- which is also reflexive and transitive. Then, usually, we write $xRy$ to mean that $(x,y) \in R$. In the case of orders, $R$ is usually written something like $\leq$, so $x \leq y$ is shorthand for $(x,y) \in {\leq}$.

In particular, taking ${\leq} \subseteq X \times X$ to be the *entire* set $X \times X$, we have that $(x,y) \in {\leq}$ always, or in other words, for any $x,y$ we have $x \leq y$. This does not seem to order much, which is what is meant by "not very restrictive".